# ReactJs: Unable to loop over array of object using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

While trying to loop over an array of object retrieved from the database in ReactJs, I always get this error

```
this.state.getCourse.map is not a function. (In 'this.state.getCourse.map(function (y) {
(Device)
        _react.default.createElement(_reactNative.Text, null, y.fullname);
      })', 'this.state.getCourse.map' is undefined)
```

I don't know why I always get this error as if I simply use

```
<Text>{this.state.getCourse}</Text>
```

it will display the saved objects in an array objects format like this

```
[{"fullname": "Gbenga", "mail": "t@j.com"},{"fullname": "Femi", "mail": "ht@h.com"}]
```

but if I looped through it, it always returned the above error.

This is what I have done so far.

```
// screens/Attendance.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

class Attendace extends Component {

 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      getCourse: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.getItem('course').then(value =>
        //AsyncStorage returns a promise so adding a callback to get the value
        this.setState({ getCourse: value })
        //Setting the value in Text 
      );
      } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}> 
        <Text>Attendance screen</Text>
         {
           this.state.getCourse.map((y) => {
             <Text>{y.fullname}</Text>
           })
         } // This will not work
        <Text>{this.state.getCourse}</Text>// This will display the array in a json format
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Attendace;
```

Comment: Check getCourse data type using typeof
`console.info(typeof this.state.getCourse )`

Comment: @AliTaee Taee inside the compondngDidMount()?

Comment: It's better to console on 
 ```render() {
     console.info(typeof this.state.getCourse )
    return (```

Comment: Looks like `AsyncStorage.getItem` returns a string in promise. 
Try `this.setState({ getCourse: JSON.parse(value) })`

Comment: @alex-bu-89 It now return Objects aree not valid as a React Child(found: object with keys{fullname,mail,course})

Comment: like @guruparan-giritharan alredy said, try `<Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.getCourse)}</Text>`

Comment: I don't need to loop over it?

Comment: @alex-bu-89 It now display, but how do I loop over it?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to render there. The whole course object, fullname, email? `<Text>` doesn't allow objects.

Comment: Why using await if you are resolving promise with then?

Comment: @alex-bu-89 To display the whole course object, using <Text> since it is a ract native project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning an object from your map function. You need to add a return or simply use the short arrow syntax like so:

```
<Text>Attendance screen</Text>
         {
           this.state.getCourse.map((y) => <Text>{y.fullname</Text>)
         } // notice the lack of {}, if you dont like this syntax just add a return before <Text ;
```

Also after you fix this React will complain about missing keys so either add an index value (not usually recommended if the array can change) or use some unique value from your datasource.

Answer (score 1):

You always save a string to async storage so do a JSON.parse

```
 await AsyncStorage.getItem('course').then(value =>
        //AsyncStorage returns a promise so adding a callback to get the value
        this.setState({ getCourse: JSON.parse(value) })
        //Setting the value in Text 
      );
```

According to your current code you try to call the map function on a string which is causing the error and you wont see the quotes when displaying that.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}> 
        <Text>Attendance screen</Text>
         {
           this.state.getCourse.map((y) => {
            return (<Text>{y.fullname}</Text>)
           })
         } // This will not work
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.getCourse)}</Text>// This will display the array in a json format
      </View>
    );
```

}

Comment: It now return Objects aree not valid as a React Child(found: object with keys{fullname,mail,course})

Comment: its bcos of   <Text>{this.state.getCourse}</Text> here you are trying to show an array inside text, so you have to use JSON.stringify(this.state.getCourse) here

Comment: Please, can I see an example

Comment: @gbengaogunbule updated the answer, please try that

Comment: Yes thats the other part, but the map should work now as you have the array

Comment: @gbengaogunbule you are not returning anything from the map, thats the issue, updated the answer

Comment: How do I make the map return what I want it to return?

Comment: As you can see, you can do this this.state.getCourse.map((y) => {
            return (<Text>{y.fullname}</Text>)
           }) or the arrow function would also work

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage.getItem('course')` is returning an object and you can't loop over that, but instead you can just directly access `fullname,course,email`  and use them in ur UI .

```
async componentDidMount(){
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.getItem('course').then(value =>
          const course = JSON.parse(value)
          if(course ) this.setState({ getCourse: course } )
      );
      } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}> 
        <Text>{this.state.getCourse.fullname }</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.getCourse.mail}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.getCourse.course}</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
```